# email form gives strange error

Tags: html, forms, email, webforms

The email form I'm trying to fix gives me an error saying:

This can not be accessed this way, you need to have an input field named 'sendtoemail'

Which is strange because i have that input field. Here's the code:

```
<h2>Contact AirKrete</h2>
    <form action="http://www.hostmonster.com/monstermail" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><p><label><input type="checkbox" name="locate " id="locate "><strong>Locate an Installer</strong></label><strong><label><input type="checkbox" name="become" id="become">Become an Installer</label></strong></p>
    <div class="left">Name:<div>
      <input name="name" type="text" id="name" onDblClick="MM_validateForm('name','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" size="40" />
    </div></div>
    <div class="left">Email:<div><input name="mailfrom" type="text" onDblClick="MM_validateForm('email','','NisEmail');return document.MM_returnValue" size="40" /></div></div>
    <div class="left">Street:<div><input name="street" type="text" id="street" onDbleClick="MM_validateForm('street','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" size="40" /></div></div>
    <div class="left">City:<div><input name="city" type="text" id="city" onDbleClick="MM_validateForm('city','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" size="40" /></div></div>
    <div class="left">State:<div><input name="state" type="text" id="state" onDblClick="MM_validateForm('state','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" size="10" /> Zip:
      <input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" onDblClick="MM_validateForm('zip','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" size="15" />
    </div></div>
    <div class="left">Country:<div><input name="country" type="text" id="country" onDblClick="MM_validateForm('country','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" size="40" /></div></div>
    <div class="left">Phone:<div><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" onDblClick="MM_validateForm('phone','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" size="40" /></div></div></p>

    <p>The fields above are REQUIRED<br>
    <strong>How did you hear about AirKrete<span style="font-size:11.0pt; ">®</span>? <br>
    Please make a selection.<span id="sprycheckbox1"><span class="checkboxRequiredMsg"></span></span></strong></p><div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="friend" id="Connection_0">Friend</label></div>
    <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="jobspec" id="Connection_1">Job Specification</label></div>
    <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="hgtv" id="Connection_2">HGTV Promotion</label></div>
    <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="web" id="Connection_3">Web Browsing</label></div>
    <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="radio" id="Connection_4">Radio</label></div>
    <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="tv" id="Connection_5">TV</label></div>
    <div class="radiox"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="other" id="Connection_6">Other</label></div></p>
    <p class="clear-fix">&nbsp;</p>
    <div><p><strong>Comments:</strong><br></p></div>
    <p><textarea name="Comments" cols="43" rows="10" id="Comments"></textarea></p>
    <p><label>If you have Attachments....</label></p>
    <p><input name="file_attachment" type="file" size="30" /></p>
    <p>When completed please click Send Email Button</p>
      <input name="sendtoemail" type="hidden" id="sendtoemail" value="info@airkrete.com" />
      <input type="submit" onClick="MM_validateForm('name','','R','zip','','R','phone','','R');return document.MM_returnValue" value="Send Email" />

      <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.airkrete.com/airkrete_thankyou.php" /><p>Thank You</p>
    </form>
```

If you know what I'm doing wrong here, some advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this on initial page/form load, or after the form is submitted? Also, I don't see any php code in your code block.

Comment: This is after the form is submitted

Comment: And yes youre right I just changed the tags.

Comment: So where is your code after the form is submitted?

Comment: What do you mean? Like the code of the page it redirects to?

Comment: Maybe. Where is the code that is producing the `This can not be accessed this way, you need to have an input field named 'sendtoemail'` error message?

Comment: http://puu.sh/lLzmY/5eb6c75e30.png I'm not hosting the page that gives me the error message. It must be a function provided by hostmonster I guess?

Comment: http://puu.sh/lLzLb/69e153b3cf.png I found this in my cpanels CGI functions. Even still I'm apparently doing everything right

Comment: Does that mean I would have to call hostmonster and make sure their CGI functions are working properly?

Comment: @JRobz I would call hostmonster and ask them how to do it. If I was hostmonster and had an email method available online accessible by the public like this one seems to be, there would be a lot more than just the 'sendtoemail' that I'd be looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I opened a live chat and talked to a representative about it. It turns out they discontinued this service but did not take it off the options they used. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

BlueMail prohibits sending a form to an email address that is not hosted on this same bluehost account.  the solution is to setup a mail forwarder in the account which can then send "forward" off site.  Then simply send the form to the address that is forwarded.